# Fastest way to retrieve word vectors of a sequence and fed into model?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, pytorch, word-embedding

For training, I have to feed the model sequence of word vector. Each sequence has on average 40 words. So, if I use a dictionary of pre-trained word embedding (like Glove), For each sequence have to hit the embedding dictionary around 40 times and for each batch, it will be around `batch_size*40` times. The dataset is divided into many batches and the whole dataset has to be iterate (epoch) several times also. So, you can imagine how many times the dictionary will get hit.
This is the approach I have done already and it is taking really a lot of time.

To solve this, I tried to make a dictionary of sequence to vector. This dictionary should contain a `sequence` as key and a 2d python list (each row is a word vector) as a value of the key. The hope is to, I just have to look for the sequence and get the values. This should decrease the time a lot but the dictionary would be very big (I estimated the size by saved the data (sequence->vectors) in mongodb and exported it and the file is 23gb). A dictionary of size 23gb should not be problem because my I am using shared server where I can allocate as much as 100gb memory. But the program gets `killed` while loading the dictionary. So this is not working.

Another approach I am thinking about is to copy the word embedding vector into pytorch's nn.Embedding().

```
input = torch.LongTensor([[1,2,4,5],[4,3,2,9]])
embedding(input)`
```

Here the numbers are indices of the word. Regarding this approach,pytorch embedding uses numpy matrix as lookup table. So, my concern is, isn’t for executing the previous code, there will be 7 hits on the numpy matrix? Or it will be retrieved parallelly? Even it runs parallelly, there should be another dictionary to convert word to indices. That also needs 7 hits on the word2indices dictionary.

So, what do you think, what is the fastest and efficient way to retrieve word vectors of a sequence and fed into model?

Comment: I would trust PyTorch to do it efficiently. Why don't measure the times yourself,? ;-) You can use [`timeit`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) in ipython.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach (copying weights in the pytorch embed) is 10 times faster than using python dictionary. The reason is, the vectors from the dictionary need to be transformed in tensor each time and this will take the most time.